# Django Template Tags in Angular Partial

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I'm trying to build a single page application with a state router which contains no specified URL. All HTML is dynamically rendered at the root of the server making use of Angular partials. My only question is how would I render server side template tags in addition to the client side angular injection, for instance a form.

```
<h1>{$ ngTitle $}</h1><!-- example of Angular injection -->

<ng-include src = "'/static/partials/navbar/anonymous.html'"></ng-include>

<!-- form that I am trying to inject from context -->

<form method = "POST" action = "/login/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Sign In">
</form>
```

As it now stands my Django template tags are rendered as verbatim text. I understand that this is a result of the order of parsing and interpretation. Django first interprets the template, Angular then interprets all the partials, never for Django to then interpret the partials as well. Is there a work around? I've looked into third party packages and I haven't really found much that could be of use.

Comment: And yes I changed the default templating notation for Angular to use dollars

Comment: I would add a view that returns a string version of the HTML.